# TYPO3: How convert SQL statement into typo3 PDO

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm having a problem with SQL(subqueries) statement when I trying to implement with "queryBuilder" at **TYPO3**. Please can you help me with this case(convert SQL statament to **TYPO3** "queryBuilder"). Thanks!

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM t2 AS t2_Tmp WHERE t2_Tmp.id = t2.id)
```

I tried with this code(example):

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
        ->getQueryBuilderForTable('table2');

return $queryBuilder->select('*')
->from('table2')
->innerJoin(
   'table2',
   'table1',
   't1',
   $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t1.id', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('t2.id'))
)
->where(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t2.date',
        $queryBuilder->addSelectLiteral($queryBuilder->expr()->max('t2.date', 'date'))
            ->from('t2','t2_tmp')
            ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t2_tmp.id', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('t2.id')))
    )
)
->execute()
->fetchAll();
```

Comment: So what did you try so far? Where exactly do you struggle?

Comment: You can see my code example

Comment: And what's the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this case and work for me.

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('table1');
$subQueryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('table2');

$queryBuilder->select('*')
        ->from('table1', 't1')
        ->innerJoin(
            't1',
            'table2',
            't2',
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t2.t1_uid', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('t1.uid')))
        ->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t2.date', '(' . $subQueryBuilder->addSelectLiteral(
                "MAX(date) FROM t2 AS t2_tmp WHERE t2_tmp.t1_uid = t2.t1_uid"
                ) . ')'
            )
        )
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like that :

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
        ->getQueryBuilderForTable('table2');

return $queryBuilder->select('*')
->from('table1', 't1')
->innerJoin(
   't1',
   'table2',
   't2',
   $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t1.id', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('t2.id'))
)
->where(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t2.date',
        $queryBuilder->addSelectLiteral("(SELECT MAX(date) FROM t2 AS t2_Tmp WHERE t2_Tmp.id = t2.id)")
    )
)
->execute()
->fetchAll();
```